# не скачивается excel - PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

почему после формирования файл не скачивается?

```
<?php
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user4215_pov', 'rd25TEXN%;=s')
        or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_client = utf8");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = utf8");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results = utf8");
    mysql_select_db('user4215_pov') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');

    require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
    $phpexcel = new PHPExcel();



    $page = $phpexcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $page->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(25);
    $page->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(25);
    $page->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(35);
    $page->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(25);
    $page->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(25);
    $page->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(25);
    $page->setCellValue("A1", "ID ЗАКАЗА");
    $page->setCellValue("B1", "ДАТА");
    $page->setCellValue("C1", "ГОТОВНОСТЬ");
    $page->setCellValue("D1", "ТОВАРЫ");
    $page->setCellValue("E1", "ВЫРУЧКА");
    $page->setCellValue("F1", "СТАТУС ОПЛАТЫ");



        $sqlu = "SELECT mo.id as idz, mo.date as dataz, mo.status as statusz, mo.gotov as gotovz, mo.price as pricez FROM modx_shopkeeper3_orders as mo WHERE DATE_FORMAT(mo.date,'%Y-%m-%d') between '".$_POST['date_minn']."' and '".$_POST['date_maxx']."' ";
                $resultrating = mysql_query($sqlu);
                $sumall = 0;
                $summa_all_count_z = 0;
                $i = 3;
    while ($parent_nameu = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultrating)) {
    $page->setCellValue("A".$i, $parent_nameu['idz']);
    $page->setCellValue("B".$i, $parent_nameu['dataz']);
    switch ($parent_nameu['gotovz']) {
        case 0:
            $page->setCellValue("C".$i, "Не готов");
            break;
        case 1:
            $page->setCellValue("C".$i, "Готов");
            break;
    }

    $sqlsp = "SELECT sum(mp.count) as sump, mp.name as namep, mp.price as pricep , mo.userid as userz, mu.username FROM modx_shopkeeper3_purchases as mp, modx_shopkeeper3_orders as mo, modx_users as mu where DATE_FORMAT(mo.date,'%Y-%m-%d') between '".$_POST['date_min']."' and '".$_POST['date_max']."' and mo.id=".$parent_nameu['idz']." and mp.order_id=mo.id AND mu.id=mo.userid   GROUP BY mp.name ORDER BY sum(mp.count) DESC";
    $resultsp = mysql_query($sqlsp);
    $summa_count = 0;
    while ($parent_nameuu = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsp)) { 
       $summa_count = $summa_count + $parent_nameuu['sump'];
       $summa_all_count_z = $summa_all_count_z + $parent_nameuu['sump'];
    }

    $page->setCellValue("D".$i, $summa_count);

    $sqlsp = "SELECT sum(mp.count) as sump, mp.name as namep, mp.price as pricep , mo.userid as userz, mu.username FROM modx_shopkeeper3_purchases as mp, modx_shopkeeper3_orders as mo, modx_users as mu where DATE_FORMAT(mo.date,'%Y-%m-%d') between '".$_POST['date_minn']."' and '".$_POST['date_maxx']."' and mo.id=".$parent_nameu['idz']." and mp.order_id=mo.id AND mu.id=mo.userid   GROUP BY mp.name ORDER BY sum(mp.count) DESC";
    $resultsp = mysql_query($sqlsp);
    $summaz = 0;
    $j = $i + 1;
    while ($parent_nameuu = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsp)) { 
        $summaz = $summaz + ($parent_nameuu['sump'] * $parent_nameuu['pricep']);
        $sumall = $sumall + ($parent_nameuu['sump'] * $parent_nameuu['pricep']);
        $page->setCellValue("D".$j, $parent_nameuu['namep']."  x".$parent_nameuu['sump']." - ".$parent_nameuu['pricep']."P");

        $j = $j+1;
    }

    $page->setCellValue("E".$i, $summaz);
    switch ($parent_nameu['statusz']) {
                                            case 1:
                                                $page->setCellValue("F".$i, "Новый");
                                                break;
                                            case 6:
                                                $page->setCellValue("F".$i, "Оплачен");
                                                break;
                                            case 7:
                                                $page->setCellValue("F".$i, "Не оплачен");
                                                break;
                                        }
                $i = $j+1;
                }   

    $i = $i+5;  
    $page->setCellValue("C".$i, "5% от оборота составило:".$sumall*0.05);
    $page->setCellValue("D".$i, $summa_all_count_z);
    $page->setCellValue("E".$i, $sumall);       

    $page->setTitle("ОТЧЕТ ЗА");


    header ( "Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT" );
     header ( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT" );
     header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
     header ( "Pragma: no-cache" );
     header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
     header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=matrix.xlsx" );

    // Выводим содержимое файла
     $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($phpexcel);
     $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Это не связано с отсутствием загрузки, но у xlsx другой content-type - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: не скачивает


header ( "Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT" );
 header ( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT" );
 header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
 header ( "Pragma: no-cache" );
 header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" );
 header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=matrix.xlsx" );